# Prove that, when k is odd, a k-regular graph must have an even number of vertices.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

For this problem I understand that a k-regular graph is a graph where all the vertices have even degrees within the graph. I understand that a k-regular graph has to have an even number of vertices, I just don't know how to proof the concepts this proof wants me to prove, I know definitions, but maybe I just don't entirely get the concept? Either way I really need help with this proof, I have no idea how to do it. Thanks so much in advance!!!!! 
Here is the question in more detail:

We say a graph G=(V,E) is a k-regular if it's sheer sequence has the form (k,k,k,...k), I.e. if every vertex has degree k. Examples of 2-regular graphs are K_3 and the "square" graph( 4 vertices and 4 edges laid out as a square).

Prove that, when k is odd, a k-regular graph must have an even number of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be familiar with the handshaking lemma for graphs. For any graph G:

$$\sum_{v\in V(G)}{deg(v)} = 2|E(G)|$$

Now assume for contradiction that there exists some k-regular graph such that k is odd, and the number of vertices is also odd. Then the sum of the degrees of the vertices in the graph would be odd.

As you can see from the handshaking lemma, the sum of the vertex degrees in any graph must always be even because it is precisely two times the number of edges in the graph.

Thus, if k is odd, every k-regular graph must have an even number of vertices.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This really helped!!

Answer (score 3):

The number of vertex-edge incidences is $2|E|$ and is also $k|V|$.